# SqlXml, i cant throw exception on wrong xml

Tags: c#, .net, clr

i wrote this code:

```
SqlXml s = new SqlXml(new MemoryStream(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes("asd")));
```

but why it doesn t give me any exception...why?

if i try:

```
SqlXml s = new SqlXml(new MemoryStream(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes("asd")));
String g=s.Value;
```

i have exception on the value assignment.
where i wrong?

thank in advance!

Comment: what does this has to do with sql-server or sql ?

Comment: because i m using on dll (CLR) on sql server...

Comment: there are thousands of possible exceptions that can be throw, which one did you get ?

Comment: but why if xml is wrong it doesn t throw exception and i have to check Value attribute to understand it??
the problem is when i call my function from sql that it has error when read Value...

Comment: maybe you should read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then ask your question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because simply calling the constructor doesn't do anything with the stream (see [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SqlXml.cs,75)) for this type. Only when you "do something" with the instance, it will actually attempt to read the data/stream, and thrown an exception if in order.

The [Value](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SqlXml.cs,152)-property is one such thing that will cause the passed stream to be actually read. There are others, check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, if you really want to use this class to check if the stream contains valid XML, then do it like you already did. Call the `SqlXml.Value` property (and maybe assign it to a string for good measure, even if you don't use it). If it throws, the XML is invalid - like you observed already.